# disable soap in wso2 api manager gateway https://IPaddr:9443/services

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

I want to disable showing soap services in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 gateway.

[image]

Because of security risks (soap action spoofing) I don't want this page to come up. How can I restrict access to this page?

Comment: I don't think you can access /services without authentication (passing credentials). How are you accessing this page?

Comment: Yes , I can access without credentials

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: how to change the config that  whole of this page (/services) doesn't come up, I mean not accessible by anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above shared screenshot presents the Axis2 services that are deployed in the respective WSO2 API Manager, and the above mentioned can be accessed using :8243 (https://localhost:8243/services) and not :9443.

You can disable listing the services by adding the following configuration to the `deployment.toml` of the respective WSO2 APIM Pack

```ini
[n_http]
'http.block_service_list'=true
```

This will block the deployed services from listing in the mentioned endpoint

Comment: Hi , https://localhost:8243/services is blocked but still I can reach this page https://ip:8243/services/Version?wsdl , how can I block acccess to all subdomains?

Comment: The above shared solution is to block only the listing of services. However, respective WSDL endpoints will be available for access. If you really want to block these paths from Internet, you can block them from your entrypoint (such as Nginx, or LoadBalancer to not to accept any requests that are matching specific paths).